# Custom Mariadb Docker Container Runs on Intel MacOS but not on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, dockerfile, mariadb

It's a school assignment.

On Mac it runs fine, but on an ubuntu distro running the container fails.

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client -y

COPY ./conf/script.sh script.sh
RUN chmod +x ./script.sh

# # TESTING
# # RUN apt-get install net-tools iputils-ping -y

ENTRYPOINT ["./script.sh"]
```

The script file, that runs at the end

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i "s|skip-networking|# skip-networking|g" /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
sed -i "s|.*bind-address\s*=.*|bind-address=0.0.0.0|g" /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

sed -i '/\[client-server\]/a\
            port = 3306\n\
            # socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\n\
            \n\
            !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/\n\
            !includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/\n\
            \n\
            [mysqld]\n\
            user = root\n\
            \n\
            [server]\n\
            bind-address = 0.0.0.0' /etc/mysql/my.cnf

echo "CNF File Modified"

service mysql start

mariadb -u root -e "alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by '$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'";
mariadb -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE wpdb";
mariadb -u root -e "CREATE USER 'wpuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'";
mariadb -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wpdb.* TO 'wpuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD'";
mariadb -u root -e "CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'";
mariadb -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'";
mariadb -u root -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES";

echo "Database Setup Complete"

mysqladmin shutdown
# exec mysqld_safe
mysqld --bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

The containerization fails at the command:

```
service mysql start
```

It just fails to start and I get no logs nothing even if I have a logfile specified in the config file.

Comment: There is no service manager in the container for which `service` can ask nicely to start MariaDB. Is using the [mariadb official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) with a few env variable too simple for your school assignment? "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" also unneeded, if in doubt read [grant](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/) (or any other user modification), there's no need for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MariaDB in Docker works with managed volume but not with mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77867808/mariadb-in-docker-works-with-managed-volume-but-not-with-mapped)